# new figure in button press

Tags: matlab

Anyone knows what is the correct syntax in opening new figure when a button was pressed in a gui mode?

how can i implement this code in gui?

```
 function GUI1
    fig1 = figure('Name', 'GUI 1');
    uicontrol('String', 'Start GUI2', 'Callback', 'GUI2');
  return;
```

same code as figure two,

if you have other codes that are easy to understand, i appreciate it a lot.

I am new to matlab and im having trouble in this one, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you just use the command 'figure' by itself on the button's callback it will create a new figure by default.  To get the figure's handle you can use 'gcf'.

Comment: how about calling another figure with functions? or i mean with textfields and buttons and static text?